# Need help deconstructing RosettaStone Huffman Code

Tags: encoding, huffman-code, rosetta-stone

I'm taking a class in C with a couple of friends. We're doing a project on Huffman Encoding and I am trying to understand the Rosetta stone version of the code. I think I've figured most of it out, but I don't understand a couple of variables.

```
typedef struct node_t {
    struct node_t *left, *right;
    int freq;
    char c;
} *node;

struct node_t pool[256] = { { 0 } };
node qqq[255], *q = qqq - 1;
```

Can someone please explain to me what *node means, and what node qqq[255] is, and what *q = qqq-1 means.

The only reason I ask is I think I am making an error somewhere in my understanding because I don't really get the relationships between these pointer nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration:

```
typedef struct node_t { ... } *node;
```

defines the `node` type as pointer to `node_t` structures (which appear to be typical binary search nodes).
So while `pool[]` is an array of `node_t` structures, `qqq[]` is an array of *pointers* (to said structures). Now think of `qqq` as a pointer to the start of some (stack reserved) bytes to hold a bunch of pointers (`255*sizeof(node)` or `255*sizeof(struct node_t*)` bytes).

Then

```
node ..., *q = ...
```

is similar in that it defines `q` as a pointer to `node`s, but without reserving any bytes. Instead, `q` is initialized to point to `qqq-1` which is probably intended to mean "point to `sizeof(node)` before `qqq`".

(While this last piece of pointer arithmetic probably works, pointing outside of `qqq` is not a good idea because adding an subtracting pointers is only defined behaviour when resulting address is within defined range.)

Supposedly, what follows is a loop where `q` is a pre-incremented iterator traversing `qqq`s data.